# How to setup Memcached with failover support in Heroku/PHP 5.6 environment?

Tags: php, session, heroku, memcached, memcachier

Recently, our PHP web app became unavailable for a few minutes since one of our Memcached nodes died (we use Memcachier as a Memcached provider).

This was our `user.ini` configuration (Heroku uses `user.ini` as a place where you define your configuration), which worked, but apparently didn't support failover:

```
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path=${MEMCACHIER_SERVERS} # I understand this is redundant, but I just kept it as-is because I didn't write the original user.ini
session.save_path="PERSISTENT=SFSESSID ${MEMCACHIER_SERVERS}"
session.gc_maxlifetime=1209600
session.gc_probability=1

memcached.sess_binary=1
memcached.sess_sasl_username=${MEMCACHIER_USERNAME}
memcached.sess_sasl_password=${MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD}
```

Our new `user.ini` configuration, which is aimed to provide failover capability

```
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path="PERSISTENT=SFSESSID ${MEMCACHIER_SERVERS}"
session.gc_maxlifetime=1209600
session.gc_probability=1

memcached.sess_sasl_username=${MEMCACHIER_USERNAME}
memcached.sess_sasl_password=${MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD}
memcached.sess_binary=1
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas=1
# I also tried memcached.sess_consistent_hash=1, to no avail
```

The `MEMCACHIER_SERVERS` env var looks like this: `123.45678.us-east-1.heroku.prod.memcachier.com:11211,123.45678.us-east-1.heroku.prod.memcachier.com:11211`. I think this means we have 2 nodes.

The problem we are getting with the new configuration are timeouts, and lots of errors regarding PHP session functions (`session_start()`, `session_write_close()`).

Why is that happening?

Remember, we're not using Memcached inside our PHP code at all, but only as our session storage engine.

I did try contacting Memcachier support, but the customer representative could only provide recommended PHP code (which we don't need).

Comment: Not quite sure about the environment, why don't you add a proxy to make it high available?

Comment: Memcachier SaaS does that for us.

Comment: what is the value of `session.gc_divisor`? Maybe the session garbage collection is started too often?

Comment: Having been in this exact situation, I would suggest moving off of the Memcachier addon to the MemcachedCloud addon--as soon as we switched, we haven't had a single issue since.  If you're using a hosted service, you shouldn't have to worry about that kind of HA unless you're building a very large app or something that truly requires 100% uptime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bounty expired and the question will get closed soon, I'm gonna go ahead with @jdotjdot's suggestion and switch from Memcachier to MemcachedCloud addon.

Comment: Welcome on board :)